# matrix not symmetric warning in Armadillo is too strict

Tags: armadillo, rcpparmadillo

The last version of armadillo gives a warning of matrix not symmetric when using inv_sympd. However, the matrix is a cross-product so I am sure it is symmetric. When I print A-arma::trans(A) I get that all the elements are 0 except one that is 1.1369e-013.

The warning causes Rstudio to crush sometimes because I am using parallel computing, so different cores can try to print at the same time and make it crush. 
How can I disable the warning or make it less strict?

Comment: Can you force it to be symmetric, e.g. by using `arma::inv_sympd(arma::symmatu(A))`? And are you certain that your matrix is positive definite (and not only symmetric)?

Comment: Thank you. What you suggest would work. However, I use the inv_sympd in many places in the code, so I would have to modify all those. Also, I am afraid it adds unnecessary operations. For the moment I am using #define ARMA_DONT_PRINT_ERRORS
#include <armadillo>

which disable all warning messages. I was just wondering if there is any way to disable only the non symmetric warning, or to modify it so that it is not so strict. 
By the way, yes, I am sure the matrix is positive definite and symmetric. A=arma::trans(X)*X+other symmetric pd matrices.

Comment: This seems to be fixed in Armadillo 9.400.3

Comment: Thank you. When I install the package RccppArmadillo in Rstudio, it seems that it installs version 9.400.2, which has the problem I described. How can I try the new version in Rstudio?

Comment: Try this in your R session: `install.packages("devtools")`  Then enable devtools: `library(devtools)`  Then install the latest RcppArmadillo from GitHub: `devtools::install_github("RcppCore/RcppArmadillo")`

Comment: It is now on CRAN and before that was available for `install.packages()` via the [RcppCore drat repo](http://rcppcore.github.io/drat/) .  I'd recommend against `install_github()`.

Comment: Thank you, problem solved. I installed again RcppArmadillo, which seems to install version 9.400.3. Now I don't get the warning. (I tried to install also devtools, but I didn't manage.)